# Is a fixed or random model more conservative in running a two way ANOVA?

Tags: mixed-model, anova, random-effects-model, fixed-effects-model

If for some reason (e.g., due to uncertainty or in error) I ran a 2 way ANOVA with one or both independent variables as fixed rather than random, or random when they are actually fixed, do I inflate the probability of a type one error for either of the main effects or the interaction (i.e., the probability of rejecting a true null hypothesis AKA alpha)?  Is one model (fixed, random, or mixed) always more conservative than another model?

(My interest in asking this question is concern about inflating alpha. Maximizing power is not the reason I posted this question, but comments on power would be of interest also.)

Comment: Please can you expand the question. "alpha" refers to a particular test. Which test are you interested in ?

Comment: @RobertLong Done.